# Clash of clans live replay issue

Tags: clash-of-clans

I opened CoC and live replay of battle appeared. However, the guy who "attacked" me didn't deploy any troop at all and after few seconds live replay screen disappeared.

I didn't have any battle log and my buildings weren't hit, there also weren't any thombstones. I don't remember if I lost any resource or trophies, but I'm pretty sure I didn't.

I think this guy just was searching for opponent and found me, but didn't start a battle.
Am I right? Have you any idea what was that?

Answer (score 1):

If you load into Clash and someone is scouting your base while looking for someone to attack, the game treats it like a battle, and only lets you watch the live replay. So yes, the person was probably just scouting your base, didn't like what they saw, and moved on